# How to set locale for all children of python app?

Tags: python, subprocess, locale

I have written an app indicator  in python for Ubuntu desktop, which calls several external programs via subprocess. It works fine under English locale , but breaks with others.

I know that there is a way to do `subprocess.call( ['command','arg1','arg3'], env=new_env_dict)` however I am interested in whether there is a way to force all `subprocess` calls have new environment instead calling it every time.

Answer (score 3):

So far I have not found a way to globally tell all `subprocess` calls to use specific environment , so I decided to go with single function that only takes list of arguments , and locale set as shown in [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13404327/3701431) but with slight variation.

```
def run_cmd(self, cmdlist):

    new_env = dict( os.environ ) 
    new_env['LC_ALL'] = 'C' 
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist,env=new_env)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    else:
        if stdout:
            return stdout
```