# How can I get a correct unicode answer from SVN command line using Python subprocess?

Tags: python, windows, svn, unicode, subprocess

#### Context

I'm using svn in Python (using a command-line wrapper with `subprocess`) on Windows and am trying to get it to work with paths/urls/filenames containing unicode characters (japanese characters in this case).

#### Issue

When running a `svn list` command on such a url, japanese characters in the response are returned as `?` bytes:

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> L = "svn list http://host/my/path/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88 --non-interactive --username TedGrassman".split(' ')
>>> r = subprocess.run(L, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> r.stdout
b'version.xml\r\n????/\r\n'
>>> r.stdout[-4]
63  # ord('?') == 63
```

The correct response, once decoded, should be (as obtained when running the command in a command prompt):

```
version.xml
フォルダ/
```

#### What I've tried

- I have tried with or without shell (`shell=True` or `shell=False`), not that it should change the outcome.
- I have tried setting the console codepage:

  ```py
  from ctypes import windll
  KERNEL32 = windll.kernel32
  KERNEL32.SetConsoleCP(65001)
  KERNEL32.SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)
  ```

  Tried with `cp65001`(`utf-8`), `cp437`(`OEM United States`), `cp932`(`ANSI/OEM Japanese; Japanese (Shift-JIS)`), `cp1242`(`ANSI Latin 1; Western European (Windows)`), and a bunch of other, to no avail.

#### Question

I am failing to see why I get erroneous bytes. I suspect this has to do with how Python's subprocess uses Windows API but I have no clue to what happens precisely.

**What would be the issue and how can I get it to return the correct characters?**

#### Environment

- Windows 10 (Build 17763)
- Python 3.6.8
- SVN 1.14.0 (from TortoiseSVN 1.14.0)

Comment: Try to set subprocess environment with locale as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404116/subprocess-popen-command-antiword-produces-different-output-in-shell-vs-web-a/13404327#13404327) answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link @viilpe. I tried setting the `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_LANG` environment variables to `en_US.UTF-8` and `ja_JP.UTF-8`, unfortunately it didn't work. I'll keep exploring this locale avenue.